# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Wireless and Ethernet Help

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

I just bought a Dell Latitude E6420 from a local computer store, and completely installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The first two days ethernet and wifi worked fine, but on day three they both just stopped working. Now it shows the wifi symbol at the top with Ethernet Network disconnected when you click on it. Did clean install and no luck. The same solutions that fixed other people's problem didn't work as well. Not sure what info I need to provide so please leave suggestions!

Comment: Both Ethernet and WiFi in a Dell Latitude E6420 are supported out-of-the-box (as you noticed) and there's absolutely no reason for them to stop working just like that and at the same time. Haven't you inadvertently toggled the "airplane mode" on? Or changed something at UEFI?

Comment: Airplane mode isn't available and I checked the BIOS to make sure WLAN was enabled and it is

Comment: If it doesn't work now after reinstalling (or in a live session) then it's defective.

Comment: So what about ethernet?

Comment: Read again. It shouldn't require further explanation because is plain logic. Both were working before, now they aren't. If the symptom persists in a live session both are either disabled or defective.

Comment: Problem solved! @CelticWarrior Physically uninstalled WLAN adapter for a few seconds then reinstalled. Works perfectly now

Comment: Take a moment to digest that valuable lesson: Always do the proper troubleshoot before asking.